# Extending TypeScript declaration files

Tags: express, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to work with TypeScript and Express. I've loaded in the type declarations from Typings and they look like this:

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/express/express.d.ts
declare module "express" {
    import * as serveStatic from "serve-static";
    import * as core from "express-serve-static-core";

    /**
     * Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level function exported by the express module.
     */
    function e(): core.Express;

    namespace e {

        /**
         * This is the only built-in middleware function in Express. It serves static files and is based on serve-static.
         */
        var static: typeof serveStatic;

        export function Router(options?: any): core.Router;

        interface Application extends core.Application { }
        interface CookieOptions extends core.CookieOptions { }
        interface Errback extends core.Errback { }
        interface ErrorRequestHandler extends core.ErrorRequestHandler { }
        interface Express extends core.Express { }
        interface Handler extends core.Handler { }
        interface IRoute extends core.IRoute { }
        interface IRouter<T> extends core.IRouter<T> { }
        interface IRouterMatcher<T> extends core.IRouterMatcher<T> { }
        interface MediaType extends core.MediaType { }
        interface NextFunction extends core.NextFunction { }
        interface Request extends core.Request { }
        interface RequestHandler extends core.RequestHandler { }
        interface RequestParamHandler extends core.RequestParamHandler { }
        export interface Response extends core.Response { }
        interface Router extends core.Router { }
        interface Send extends core.Send { }
    }

    export = e;
}
```

Now I'm trying to extend the prototype for all Response objects like so:

```
const express = require('express');
express.response.sendWrapped = function(obj: Object, meta?: Object) {
    return this.json({
        data: obj
    });
};
```

Now I just need to get the extension into the typings. I would love to just extend this method into the existing definition, much like how I have extended it in the prototype, but I am unsure how to do so.

Since this is a personal extension of the type definition for the library, I do **not** believe this belongs back with the master typing set and I should **not** have to modify them manually for my own purposes. What is the best way to extend them in my own way? Can I do it without overriding every other piece dependent on Response?

Answer (score 2):

Using TypeScript 2.0 or a pre-release of it (`typescript@next`) you can use module augmentation syntax to augment the definition of `express` to include your new `response` definition:

```js
import express = require('express');

declare module "express" {
    namespace response {
        function sendWrapped(obj: any, meta?: any): void;
    }
}

express.response.sendWrapped = function(obj: Object, meta?: Object) {
    return this.json({
        data: obj
    });
};
```

Comment: Does this have to be declared in the TS file or can it go in the d.ts?

Comment: you can do this in both a .ts and .d.ts

Comment: How did you get your typescript 2.0 to recognize the express framework?

Answer (score -1):

A few things:

(1) There's no `response` in the declarations you included, there's a `Response`, so it should be: `express.Response.sendWrapped`.

(2) You did not extend the prototype for all `Response`s, you added the `sendWrapped` function to the class itself (I assume that `Response` is a class).
If you want to add to the prototype it should look like:

```
express.Response.prototype.sendWrapped = function(obj: Object, meta?: Object) {
    return this.json({
        data: obj
    });
};
```

(3) You can add to an existing type like so:

```
namespace express {
    interface Response {
        sendWrapped(obj: Object, meta?: Object): any;
    }
}
```

More about that in [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

---

#### Edit

If it's in a `d.ts` file then you need it to be:

```
declare namespace express {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't let you merge declarations and I don't have this setup to test it on my own, but I have another solution for you which is, in my opinion, better.

Just extend `express.Response` add what ever you need in there, for example:

```
class MyResponse extends express.Response {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    sendWrapped(obj: Object, meta?: Object): express.Response {
        return this.json({
            data: obj
        });
    }
}
```

This is better because you're not as vulnerable for changes in the express api, and more than that, this is what object oriented is for.

Comment: There is a bit of a mismatch here because of how Express works under the hood. The actual prototype is under `response`, while the definition is under `Response`. But that's an implementation detail. What I need is to just update the interface to work accordingly. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these seem to work for me. I was most hopeful about #3, but when it's own .d.ts file I get this error: `A 'declare' modifier is required for a top level declaration in a .d.ts file.`. If I try to add the namespace in a normal .ts file, I get this error: `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'express'`

Comment: The `declare namespace` suggestion eliminates the compile errors, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on `Response` where it is called. Unfortunately, extending the class is not a very clean approach here. Response objects are passed to other functions via type inference, and I would have to override every single one of them to add a new method. For example: `router.get('/users/', (req, res) => /* res is of type Response via declarations */ );`

Comment: I believe there is an outstanding TypeScript issue for supporting this better. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/819

Comment: Looks exactly what I said, you declare it again and add the needed members/methods (only I used `interface` and they used `class`). If there's no compilation error but it doesn't have the method in run time then the way you actually add the method is wrong, probably something to do with the prototype issue you mentioned.

Comment: I should have been more clear -- this is perfectly valid runtime code, but it is invalid TypeScript code. `sendWrapped` does not appear valid to TypeScript since I can't extend the definitions, but the prototype is extended properly.

Comment: You wrote: `The declare namespace suggestion eliminates the compile errors, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on Response where it is called`, and in the link you provided they also seem to extend the definitions in a similar way.